# Problemas Con Trigger De Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo problemas para realizar un trigger en Oracle, la idea es que este se ejecute al insertar un registro dentro de el estoy una función la cual realizara calculo entre dos valores (precio y cantidad) al final espero que el trigger el campo total de la tabla se actualice con el monto total a pagar del pedido.

He intentado hacerlo de esta forma y el campo total queda null

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trgCalcularTotal BEFORE INSERT ON Pedidos FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE Pedidos 
   SET Total = fncalcularPrecio(:new.Precio,:new.Cantidad)
   WHERE idPedido = :new.idPedido;
END;
```

Y de esta Forma me actualiza todos los registros anteriores pero el ultimo que inserto queda en null

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trgCalcularTotal BEFORE INSERT ON Pedidos FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE Pedidos 
   SET Total = fncalcularPrecio(Precio, Cantidad)
   WHERE idPedido = idPedido;
END;
```

Como puedo resolver mi problema?

Answer (score 0):

No tienes que hacer el `update`, solo tienes que llenar el campo total con el resultado:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trgCalcularTotal BEFORE INSERT ON Pedidos FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :new.Total := fncalcularPrecio(:new.Precio,:new.Cantidad);

END;
```